# Convert daily data arranged in each column for a month into time-series

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several years of daily discharge data provided in fixed-width ".txt" format as follows:

Year:           1962

```
                                Mean daily discharge in m3/s
                                ============================

Day     Jan.   Feb.   Mar.   Apr.   May    Jun.   Jul.   Aug.   Sep.   Oct.   Nov.   Dec.   Year
 01     NA     NA      169    205    458    472    975   2010   1310    755    307    214
 02     NA     NA      163    205    467    462    952   2590   1230    800    307    211
 03     NA     NA      160    198    410    415    946   2340   1220    687    303    211
 04     NA     NA      158    189    396    392    946   2200   1160    675    303    208
 05     NA     NA      195    180    365    467   1040   2090   1230    652    299    205
 06     NA     NA      231    192    335    508   1150   2030   1260    634    295    205
 07     NA     NA      202    195    311    566   1250   1970   1230    628    291    202
 08     NA     NA      198    192    291    640   1220   1860   1160    611    288    202
 09     NA     NA      195    195    284    813   1100   1800   1180    588    280    198
 10     NA     NA      192    192    273    981   1050   1690   1260    577    273    198
 11     NA     NA      192    195    269   1030    946   1570   1160    555    269    195
 12     NA     NA      189    189    265   1000   1100   1850   1110    539    265    192
 13     NA     NA      189    186    262   1050   1040   1830   1090    518    265    192
 14     NA     NA      186    198    269   1060    934   1790   1180    503    262    189
 15     NA     NA      192    205    280   1150   1300   1900   1120    492    258    186
 16     NA     NA      192    211    295   1170   1470   2080   1160    467    255    183
 17     NA     NA      192    205    315    877   1490   2140   1260    453    255    183
 18     NA     NA      192    208    311    807   3030   1990   1130    448    251    180
 19     NA     NA      192    214    284    774   1360   1940   1700    434    248    180
 20     NA     NA      189    238    277    915   1310   1880   1830    429    244    178
 21     NA     NA      189    238    303   1020   1240   1780   1640    415    241    175
 22     NA     NA      186    277    319   1200   1200   1420   1860    406    238    175
 23     NA      160    183    269    323   1280   1120   1350   1940    392    234    172
 24     NA      163    183    315    357   1360   1160   1340   1650    369    231    169
 25     NA      178    186    361    365   1380   1260   1570   1420    357    227    169
 26     NA      169    189    361    365   1340   1360   1730   1220    344    224    169
 27     NA      169    189    410    365   1300   1810   1880   1130    335    221    166
 28     NA      169    192    434    387   1250   2090   1640   1040    327    218    166
 29     NA             195    419    419   1210   1800   1550    981    311    218    163
 30     NA             202    387    415   1150   1800   1500    969    311    214    163
 31     NA             205           438          1850   1690           307           163

Min     NA     NA      158    180    262    392    934   1340    969    307    214    163   NA  
Mean    NA     NA      189    249    338    936   1330   1840   1290    494    259    186   NA  
Max     NA     NA      231    434    467   1380   3030   2590   1940    800    307    214   NA
```

My goal is to convert it into time series. I have tried to use read.fwf() to read the file and pivot_longer() function to acquire the time series. But the problem is I couldn't specify the number of days in each month thus got 372 days. Since I am a newbie to r I am not familiar with many r-packages. Could anyone here suggest a simpler way to achieve my goal? Thank you!

Comment: Use `values_drop = T` in `pivot_longer`

Comment: @ANilGoyal Yah values_drop = T works however, it omits all the NAs available in the dataset which I don't want to omit.

Comment: That's not a problem.  You can use `tidyr::complete` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
df <- read.table(text = "Day     Jan.   Feb.   Mar.   Apr.   May.    Jun.   Jul.   Aug.   Sep.   Oct.   Nov.   Dec.
 01     NA     NA      169    205    458    472    975   2010   1310    755    307    214
 02     NA     NA      163    205    467    462    952   2590   1230    800    307    211
 03     NA     NA      160    198    410    415    946   2340   1220    687    303    211
 04     NA     NA      158    189    396    392    946   2200   1160    675    303    208
 05     NA     NA      195    180    365    467   1040   2090   1230    652    299    205
 06     NA     NA      231    192    335    508   1150   2030   1260    634    295    205
 07     NA     NA      202    195    311    566   1250   1970   1230    628    291    202
 08     NA     NA      198    192    291    640   1220   1860   1160    611    288    202
 09     NA     NA      195    195    284    813   1100   1800   1180    588    280    198
 10     NA     NA      192    192    273    981   1050   1690   1260    577    273    198
 11     NA     NA      192    195    269   1030    946   1570   1160    555    269    195
 12     NA     NA      189    189    265   1000   1100   1850   1110    539    265    192
 13     NA     NA      189    186    262   1050   1040   1830   1090    518    265    192
 14     NA     NA      186    198    269   1060    934   1790   1180    503    262    189
 15     NA     NA      192    205    280   1150   1300   1900   1120    492    258    186
 16     NA     NA      192    211    295   1170   1470   2080   1160    467    255    183
 17     NA     NA      192    205    315    877   1490   2140   1260    453    255    183
 18     NA     NA      192    208    311    807   3030   1990   1130    448    251    180
 19     NA     NA      192    214    284    774   1360   1940   1700    434    248    180
 20     NA     NA      189    238    277    915   1310   1880   1830    429    244    178
 21     NA     NA      189    238    303   1020   1240   1780   1640    415    241    175
 22     NA     NA      186    277    319   1200   1200   1420   1860    406    238    175
 23     NA      160    183    269    323   1280   1120   1350   1940    392    234    172
 24     NA      163    183    315    357   1360   1160   1340   1650    369    231    169
 25     NA      178    186    361    365   1380   1260   1570   1420    357    227    169
 26     NA      169    189    361    365   1340   1360   1730   1220    344    224    169
 27     NA      169    189    410    365   1300   1810   1880   1130    335    221    166
 28     NA      169    192    434    387   1250   2090   1640   1040    327    218    166
 29     NA      NA     195    419    419   1210   1800   1550    981    311    218    163
 30     NA      NA     202    387    415   1150   1800   1500    969    311    214    163
 31     NA      NA     205    NA     438   NA     1850   1690   NA      307    NA     163
", header = T)

df %>% pivot_longer(!Day, values_drop_na = T) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0('2017','.', name, Day ), format = '%Y.%b.%d')) %>%
  select(-Day, name) %>%
  complete(date = seq.Date(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2017-12-31'), by = '1 day'))

# A tibble: 365 x 3
   date       name  value
   <date>     <chr> <int>
 1 2017-01-01 NA       NA
 2 2017-01-02 NA       NA
 3 2017-01-03 NA       NA
 4 2017-01-04 NA       NA
 5 2017-01-05 NA       NA
 6 2017-01-06 NA       NA
 7 2017-01-07 NA       NA
 8 2017-01-08 NA       NA
 9 2017-01-09 NA       NA
10 2017-01-10 NA       NA
# ... with 355 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored in `test.dat` you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("test.dat") %>% 
  pivot_longer(Jan.:Dec., values_drop = T)  %>% 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, "[.]")) %>% 
  mutate(Year = "1962") %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy(paste(Day, name, Year, sep = "/")))
```